# Is there any way to retrieve specific text from a file

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm working on a code to write into isolated storage the username and password.
I wrote the code but I have to read password to `Passwordtext` from file and username from the same file to another textbox.
Is there any way to retrieve these specific values from a file?

Comment: I've tried to define to stream writer and reader to put the name in a file and the pass in another one but this way not useful>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object to hold the data you're after and serialize it and write it to a file. Then read out and deserialize to access the data.

Alternatively you could store these in `IsolatedStorageSettings` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I know but my problem that i wanna determin what to get from the file for exampl call only a password string from the file